# rails 2 and ruby 1.9.2 sort_by on array of multiple hashes of different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sorting, activerecord, hash

I am working on sorting the array object which is having multiple hashes from two different model I need to sort with one fieled having different name on other model

Array object is following

```
 [#<TechpackAttachment id: 16, company_id: 1, version_id: 38, techpack_identifier: "5bb55062-db53-11e3-abae-d43d7e129fac", body: nil, attachment_description: nil, document_file_name: "sandle.jpg", document_content_type: "image/jpeg", document_file_size: 5717, document_updated_at: "2014-05-22 10:15:36", creator_id: 1, updater_id: 1, created_at: "2014-05-22 10:15:36", updated_at: "2014-05-22 10:15:36", is_primary_image: false>, #<SampleImage id: 13, company_id: 1, vendor_id: 1, sample_id: 4, body: nil, attachment_description: nil, private_to_vendor: 0, image_file_name: "53.png", image_content_type: "image/png", image_file_size: 318585, image_updated_at: "2014-02-19 13:24:05", creator_id: 1, updater_id: 1, created_at: "2014-02-19 13:24:05", updated_at: "2014-02-19 13:24:05", is_primary_image: false>  ]
```

In above object i need to sort by document_file_name which is having different name in SampleImage model it is image_file_name .

what i did is

```
    @rec = @rec.sort_by {|i| i.document_file_name.nil? ? i.image_file_name : i.document_file_name }
```

giving me error

```
  undefined method `document_file_name' for #<SampleImage:0xa9cb9298>
```

**EDIT**

I just put two models for example but there are 10 models in array objects and some of them are having document and other having image in their hash .

Comment: yes that i know but array is combination of two models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect if object responds to `document_file_name` method:

```
@rec = @rec.sort_by do |i|
  if i.respond_to?(:document_file_name)
    i.document_file_name
  else
    i.image_file_name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help.

```
@rac = [#<TechpackAttachment id: 16, company_id: 1, version_id: 38, techpack_identifier: "5bb55062-db53-11e3-abae-d43d7e129fac", body: nil, attachment_description: nil, document_file_name: "sandle.jpg", document_content_type: "image/jpeg", document_file_size: 5717, document_updated_at: "2014-05-22 10:15:36", creator_id: 1, updater_id: 1, created_at: "2014-05-22 10:15:36", updated_at: "2014-05-22 10:15:36", is_primary_image: false>, #<SampleImage id: 13, company_id: 1, vendor_id: 1, sample_id: 4, body: nil, attachment_description: nil, private_to_vendor: 0, image_file_name: "53.png", image_content_type: "image/png", image_file_size: 318585, image_updated_at: "2014-02-19 13:24:05", creator_id: 1, updater_id: 1, created_at: "2014-02-19 13:24:05", updated_at: "2014-02-19 13:24:05", is_primary_image: false>  ]  

@rec = @rec.sort_by { |i| i.kind_of?(TechpackAttachment) ? i.document_file_name : i.image_file_name }
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer (the part without code).

Comment: I just separate the object with there class name.

Comment: I know. I understand this part. What I don't understand is "I this this is helpful." sentence.

Comment: Now that's better. Though it should be a little bit more descriptive, I think.